# Counting rows between two specific rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to count the number of rows between two specific rows on my sheet. Here's what it looks like:

```
500
501
5011
502
600
```

So in this case there's 3 rows between 500 and 600. The reason I want to do this is so if there are rows added or removed between "500" and "600", I won't need to update the script.

Would appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: Are cells added via apps script, that's why the tag? If not, let 500 be in A1 and 600 in A5: `=SUM(A1:A5)-A1-A5`..

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do it all in apps script. The formula you provided wouldn't work if rows were added or removed in between since the row position would change.

Answer (score 0):

If there will never be another "500" or "600" between the first and the last number you could use something like this.

```
function myFunction() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
 for (row in data)
 {
   //To no include the row with the 500 you need to add +1
   if (data[row] == 500) var first = row+1
    if (data[row] == 600) var last = row
 }
 var distance = last - first
}
```

Final answer in var distance

If there might be other "500" or "600" but the "600" will always be the last row you can simply replace the

```
 if (data[row] == 600) var last = row
```

by

```
 var last = sheet.getLastRow()
```

Hope this helps
If unclear ask question and I will reply in the comments